# Как правильно организовать экран настроек в приложении?

Tags: android-sdk, android, java, android-fragment

Здравствуйте! В интернете читаю, что обычно делают активити

```
    public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity {
```

В моем приложении есть `navigationDrawer`, и в одном из пунктов хочу сделать "Настройки", чтобы появлялся очередной фрагмент, аналогичный `PreferenceActivity`. Правильно ли так поступать?

Как я уже понял, проще работать с `Aсtivity`, т.к. больше методов доступно. Для меня это преимущество, ввиду отсутствия опыта.

Comment: Если нужен фрагмент, то в SDK имеется [`PreferenceFragment`][1]. Но он доступен с API 11 и выше.

  [1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html

Comment: @falstaf спасибо, но предпочтительнее конечно под 8 level

Comment: Тогда у вас, увы, не остаётся иного выхода, кроме как использовать `PreferenceActivity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже сказали, для API 11+ есть [PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html). Я приложения с поддержкой более ранних версий всегда делаю, так что этот вариант не подходит.

Так что, либо в обычном фрагменте все контролы самому делать, или воспользоваться [этим](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14092811/1991579) решением, например.